# Find date value in an array in PHP

Tags: php, find

I have dates stored in an array but defining date ranges in a special format like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array ///date start
                (
                    [0] => 2017
                    [1] => 10 //month
                    [2] => 3 //day
                )

            [1] => Array //date end
                (
                    [0] => 2017
                    [1] => 10 //month
                    [2] => 5 //day
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array //date start
                (
                    [0] => 2017
                    [1] => 11
                    [2] => 23
                )

            [1] => Array //date end
                (
                    [0] => 2017
                    [1] => 11
                    [2] => 25
                )

        )

)
```

And I would need a function that can return if a specific string date exist in the array

```
2017-10-01. is_in_array ('2017-10-01').
```

But I don't understand how can I do with the foreach  and the special array format of the date ranges.

Comment: So, what if you had a range like `[[2017, 10, 3], [2017, 10, 5]]` and you wanted to check the date `2017-10-04`, should it find it or not?

Comment: the function returns true

Comment: but the end date is not included, so for 2017-10-05, function should returns false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need time in the mix you can try this variant

```
<?php
$discountDatesArr = [
    [[2018, 8,  5, '00:00:00'], [2018, 8,  9, '23:59:59']],
    [[2018, 8,  15, '00:00:00'], [2018, 8,  15, '23:59:59']],
    [[2018, 8,  19, '00:00:00'], [2018, 8,  19, '23:59:59']],
    [[2018, 8,  22, '00:00:00'], [2018, 8,  22, '23:59:59']],
    [[2018, 8,  29, '00:00:00'], [2018, 8,  29, '23:59:59']],
];

$isDiscountSystemActive = false;
$dateUnix = strtotime(date("Y-n-j H:i:s"));
foreach ($discountDatesArr as $range) {
    $rangeStartUnix = strtotime("{$range[0][0]}-{$range[0][1]}-{$range[0][2]} {$range[0][3]}");
    $rangeEndUnix   = strtotime("{$range[1][0]}-{$range[1][1]}-{$range[1][2]} {$range[1][3]}");
    if ($dateUnix >= $rangeStartUnix && $dateUnix < $rangeEndUnix) {
        $isDiscountSystemActive = true;
    }
}
define ("ISDISCOUNTACTIVE", $isDiscountSystemActive);
echo ISDISCOUNTACTIVE;
```

https://eval.in/1044922

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$arr = array(

    [
        [2017,10,3],
        [2017,10,5]
    ],
    [
        [2017,11,23],
        [2017,11,25]
    ],
    [
        [2017,12,1],
        [2017,12,10]
    ]

);

function is_in_array($array, $date) {
    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    $date = date('d',$timestamp);
    $month = date('m',$timestamp);
    $year = date('Y',$timestamp);
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        foreach($value as $value2) {
            if($value2[0]==$year && $value2[1] == $month && $date == $value2[2])
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here first parameter to `is_in_array()` is an array from which you want to find date
and second parameter is date that you are looking for.
Therefore

```
is_in_array('2017-12-1'); //will return true
is_in_array('2017-5-2'); //will return false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$rangesArr = [
    [[2017, 10,  3], [2017, 10,  5]],
    [[2017, 11, 23], [2017, 11, 25]],
];

function is_in_array ($date) {
    global $rangesArr;
    $dateUnix = strtotime($date);
    foreach ($rangesArr as $range) {
        $rangeStartUnix = strtotime("{$range[0][0]}-{$range[0][1]}-{$range[0][2]}");
        $rangeEndUnix   = strtotime("{$range[1][0]}-{$range[1][1]}-{$range[1][2]}");
        if ($dateUnix >= $rangeStartUnix && $dateUnix < $rangeEndUnix) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var_dump(is_in_array('2017-10-04')); // Returns true.
var_dump(is_in_array('2017-10-05')); // Returns false.
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Basically, all it does is loop through the array, convert the sub range start and end arrays into unix timestamps, and compares that with the unix timestamp of the date that was passed in.

[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/891646)

Comment: thanks a lot i will check this !! is there any difference in between 2017-10-04 and 2017-10-4 ?

Comment: thanks , is your script compatible with the multidimensional array described in my post  because for the moment the function always returns false...

Comment: @Pipoo make sure you updated `global $rangesArr;` and `foreach ($rangesArr as $range) {` to the correct array name. Yes it's compatible, it's the exact same format, just condensed.

Comment: yes i pasted your function , but if you tell that $rangesArr is the same than my array, it must be my mistake, i am checking it...